# LINQ stopped working after upgrade to VS 2010 and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-2008, freeze

I have started using Visual Studio 2010 recently. I have upgraded my solution from old 2008. After this I have tried to run my project, which is very simple database search engine using linq commands and it worked. Then I have switched to .NET 4 and since then I am dead in the water. Any linq query does not execute, nor any exception is thrown. When I pause while the linq command is being executed, it freezes on DataContext.GetTable() method. All I could come up with were some compatibility issues, but I could not figure out what exactly the problem is.

My Linq command is typical "select *":

```
var query = from mateInfo in context.TableMateInfos
                        select mateInfo;
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. I do not have any clue, why command execution should stop working after upgrade to .NET 4, especially because I am still able to connect to database. When I open DB in Management studio, SQL command (select * from TableMateInfo) works just fine and returns data I want. Does anybody have any ideas, where the burried dog might be please?

**EDIT:**

I have run my application by its' exe file, following exception has been thrown:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(SignatureStruct& signature, Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeFieldInfo fieldHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.get_FieldType()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.TypeSystem.GetMemberType(MemberInfo mi)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember..ctor(AttributedMetaType metaType, MemberInfo mi, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType.InitDataMembers()
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType..ctor(MetaModel model, MetaTable table, Type type, MetaType inheritanceRoot)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedRootType..ctor(AttributedMetaModel model, AttributedMetaTable table, Type type)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaTable..ctor(AttributedMetaModel model, TableAttribute attr, Type rowType)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaModel.GetTableNoLocks(Type rowType)
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaModel.GetTable(Type rowType)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable[TEntity]()
```

I have added app.config file with following content to the same exact location where exe file and all libraries are located. Still I got the error above.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What are you using, LINQ2SQL, LINQ2Entites, LINQ2Fishticks? Can you reproduce it with a brand new project, connect it to a NEW database, create a model and some queries and check if the same thing happens.

Comment: I am using LINQ2SQL. I'll try the new project, that is probably a good idea

Comment: i think you are facing `System.Data.Linq` namespace type error.plz check that your pages is having `System.Data.Linq` namespace or not.

Comment: Are you using the System.Data.Linq namespace? That is most probably your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately yes :( I suspect it would also cause the compilation error so I could not run my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in different versions of .NET used to build single projects after all. The app.config file above would work if there already weren't one without `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` attribute. I had to add it manually, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `Linq` namespace problem, Just do one thing

```
Go to [project name] -> References -> Add reference -> System.Data.Linq
```

Add `System.Data.Linq` namespace by `Add references`.

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Nope, it is among my references